creating sliding surface between composite and metal
I am designing a Battery pack for a Prototype Battery electric car. The pack is going to be made out of fibre glass foam sandwich composite panels and with the modules and electronics its going to weigh approximately 70 kg. For servcing the battery pack needs to come out of the car. My current plan is to have the pack slide out on a sheet metal rail that has a cnc'd nylon layer on top. I don't really know that much about using nylon like this.How thick should the nylon layer be? Do i need to coat the battery packs sliding surface with something? Is there any other material that would work better than nylon?
The blue highlight is the part of the pack that is going to slide


Be advised that nylon absorbs moisture and can swell with high humidity. Delrin is often a better option.

One suitable option that you have in addition to the commented suggestion of Delrin™ is to use UHMWPE, aka, ultrahigh molecular weight polyethylene which is astonishingly slippery. You could also try its cousins, HDPE and LDPE, but the UHMWPE is more durable in my opinion.
From the linked site, one of many returned from a search for UHMWPE:

UHMW (ultra high molecular weight polyethylene) is an extremely tough
plastic with high abrasion and wear resistance. The versatility of
polyethylene has made it a popular plastic for countless industrial
applications that require durability, low friction, and chemical
resistance. Applications include UHMW wear strips, chain guides,
packaging machinery parts, and marine dock fender pads.

Decades ago, a friend showed me his tractor-trailer rig which had a fifth-wheel shim made of the stuff. It was about 10 mm thick, possibly thicker and coated with grease from the various trailers pulled by the rig. The plastic is tough, but easy to cut, akin to cutting aluminum. Machining it is fun, as the milling bit wants to send off a continuous ribbon, unless the cut is adjusted to prevent that. Then it's a volume filled with tiny floating fragments with static cling!
If you use any lubricant, consider to use a silicone based product, although UHMWPE is notoriously inert and nearly impossible to glue to anything. You may want to try the assembly without lubricant to see how little force is required, then apply some and watch the stuff slide like it was on ice.
